# Fortran runtime error: End of file in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When I run this program using gfortran test.f95, it shows an error

```
At line 10 of file test.f95 (unit = 15, file = 'open.dat')

Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

```
implicit none
integer:: a,b,c,ios

open(unit=15,file="open.dat",status='unknown', action='readwrite',iostat=ios)
open(unit=16,file="open.out",status="unknown",action='write')

do a=1,100
  write(15,*)a
end do

do c=1,45,1
  read(15,*)
  read(15,*)b
  write(16,*)b
end do

stop
end
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. If you exactly copy and paste the error message into the title, the system will tell you that such a question already exists. It is possible it had already told you so, so you had to change it slightly. Please, you really should read the existing questions first. Also, it is very important to show us the data you are reading.

Comment: BTW there is no point in passing `status='unknown'` and using `stop` before `end`. You can just delete that.

Comment: you should also not specify `iostat` and then not handle the result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change location in the file with ***rewind***/***fseek***

```
implicit none
integer :: a, b, c, ios, ierr

open( unit=15, file="open.dat", action='readwrite', iostat=ios)
open( unit=16, file="open.out", action='write')
do a=1,100
  write(15,*)a
end do

! Here we need to get back to beginning of file
! otherwise, you try to read where you finished writing
! at the end of file
! CALL FSEEK(UNIT, OFFSET, WHENCE[, STATUS])
! https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FSEEK.html
! call fseek(15, 0, 0, ierr)

! you can also use rewind file
! https://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-12.html
rewind(15)

do c=1,45,1
  read(15,*)
  read(15,*)b
  write(16,*)b
end do

end
```

Comment: You could also do that with **rewind(15)**

Comment: I do not recommend fseek at all. Standard Fortran is powerful enough.

Comment: Still clinging to the non-standard and non-portable `fseek` :-)

Comment: C heritage ;) But, after all, rewind is 'the choosen one' in the final code ;)

Comment: Thank you all. I fixed up my problem using rewind.

Comment: .oOo. Have fun ;)! .oOo.